# Why is my bevel modifier not making changes when I change the values?

Tags: edit-mode

It does not matter what values I put into my bevel modifier, it doesn't change anything. Why is that? (picture 1)

**EDIT:** = picture 2

So I wanted to have a cleaner base object. However, I am having the same issue with the main shape now. I am looking at the Bevel amount and dimensions. I don't see an issue there?
It is also not bevelling the edges on the backside.

Can I also have a different bevel amount on the inner circle compared to the outer edges of the shape?

I added the new file: [image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Your bevel *Amount* is much too high. The d-pad has a thickness in Y direction of 0.038 m, which means you cannot bevel more than 0.019 m before it overlaps. Your *Amount* is set to 0.4 m, that's more than 20× higher.

Since the *Clamp Overlap* option is enabled by default in the *Bevel* modifier, no changes above an amount of 0.019 m will be visible because it is clamped. Change the value to something lower and the bevel will show changes. Or disable *Clamp Overlap* which will of course look awful.

[image]

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is due to *clamping*, once you decrease the value below the clamping threshold, you can see the changes:

[image]

The clamping is there to ensure the created faces don't overlap, creating ugly artifacts.

Imagine that you have a thermostat and input a desired temperature using a keypad. It's reasonable for the thermostat to clamp the input to some maximum e.g. 30°C. So changing the temperature from 35°C to 40°C won't affect the temperature in the room, because after clamping, both settings get converted to the same 30°C.

Comment: Ah thank you! That makes so much more sense!